I get an error when running Grunt-Contrib-Jasmine. When I try to run Grunt Jasmine in terminal I get the output "error from puppeteer"
This is my first time installing grunt-contrib-jasmine to a project I am working on. I can't seem to figure out how to get Grunt to read my test file. Any tips or insights would be very appreciated.
Here is my gruntFile.js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({ 
        concat: {
            release: {
                src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js', 'js/getImages.js',       'js/replaceImages.js', 'js/main.js'],
                dest: 'release/main.js'
            }
        },
        
        copy: {
            release: {
                src: 'manifest.json',
                dest: 'release/manifest.json'
            }
        },
        
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            
            files: ['release/main.js']
        },
        
        watch: {
            files: ['js/*.js', 'mainfest.json'],
            tasks: ['default']
            },
            
        jsdoc: { 
            dist: { 
                src: ['js/*.js'],
                dest: 'doc'
            }
        },
        
        jasmine: { 
            test: {
            src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js', 'js/getImages.js', 'js/replaceImages.js', 'js/main.js'],
            options: {
                specs: 'test/*.js'
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsdoc');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
    
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'jshint', 'copy']);
    
    };
    

when I run Grunt Jasmine in terminal it gives me the output
Running "jasmine:test" (jasmine) task

  Puppeteer old Headless deprecation warning:
    In the near feature `headless: true` will default to the new Headless mode
    for Chrome instead of the old Headless implementation. For more
    information, please see https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/.
    Consider opting in early by passing `headless: "new"` to `puppeteer.launch()`
    If you encounter any bugs, please report them to https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/new/choose.


Testing specs with Jasmine/latest via HeadlessChrome/112.0.5614.0
>> Error caught from Puppeteer
Warning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at LifecycleWatcher._LifecycleWatcher_createTimeoutPromise (/Users/kennethcasias/eclipse-workspace/kittenbook/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:162:12) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Grunt Jasmine. I have tried installed Grunt Jasmine globally.

I can open the Jasmine SpecRunner.html to see my tests. The command within terminal is still not working as expected.
